# Cannot start sensu-service due to libc6 error

Tags: ruby, sensu

I am trying to install `sensu-client` on Ubuntu 16.04 node and after installation I am unable to start the service. Below is the error I am getting while trying to start the service.

```
 sensu-service[4885]: /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.4)
```

My `sensu` version is 1.9.0-2

I have verified that `libc6` is already installed in my node

```
$sudo dpkg -l | grep libc6
ii  libc6:amd64                      2.23-0ubuntu11.3                           amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-dev:amd64                  2.23-0ubuntu11.3                           amd64        GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
```

Is there a way I can make them work with current os version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 is the LTSC version but right now, it is only receiving security updates so the version of `libc6` isn't going to be updated and normally isn't anyway.

Sensu 1.# has been EOL since December 31st 2019 and has been superseded by Sensu Go as stated here: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sensu/1.9.0

You could try an older version of it that's compatible with the version of `libc6` that you have but I'd recommend against that because it's no longer supported.

The best option in your case is to install Sensu Go on a system that has Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 which have, respectively, `libc6` versions 2.27 and 2.31. The Sensu that you have would install and run on a later release of Ubuntu but again, it's no longer supported.